# Optimal way to get a JList selectedvalue from another class

Tags: java, eclipse, singleton, instance, jlist

I am making a database manager which shows you a JTable with all the table data. The ideas is to have in the left side a JList with the table names where you can select the table to visualize.

So i have a class where I manage all the table data and so, an another one for the JList.

The JList class extends from JPanel and I created a getInstance() method so I can just create one instance of JList. I also have a method called getSelectedValue() that is mainly called in the JTable class to display the selected table information.

But this way I am having problems, I debug and I get an error in the JList constructor, here os the code:

```
public class DatabaseJList extends JPanel {

private static DatabaseJList instance = null;
private static DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
private static JList list;

  public DatabaseJList() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    model = new DefaultListModel();

    list = new JList(model);
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(list);

    Vector<String> vector = new Vector(DatabaseTableManagers.getInstance().getTableNames());
    for( int i=0; i<vector.size() ; i ++ )
    {
        String string = vector.elementAt(i);

        model.addElement(string);   

    }


    add(pane, BorderLayout.NORTH);

  }

public Object getSelectedObject() {
    return list.getSelectedValue();

}
public void setSelectedObject(String str)
{
    list.setSelectedValue(str, true);
}



public static DatabaseJList getInstance()
{
    if (instance == null)
    {
        instance =  new DatabaseJList();
    }
    return instance;

}
```

When the getInstance method is called for first time and it proceeds to make the "new DatabaseJList();" it goes to the constructor and stops, at less thats what I see with my poor debuging knowledge. Any ideas? Thanks everyone ;)

Comment: Off-topic: having a static method return a single instance, it's called a singleton pattern and in that, you make the constructor private(or protected) so the class itself cannot be instantiated normally.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine for me. Here's what I tried (some minor tweaks, nothing drastic)

```
public class DatabaseJList extends JPanel {

    private static DatabaseJList instance = null;
    private static DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    private static JList list;

    public DatabaseJList() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();

        list = new JList(model);
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(list);

        Vector<String> vector = new Vector<String>();
        vector.add("test1");
        vector.add("test2");
        for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++) {
            String string = vector.elementAt(i);

            model.addElement(string);

        }

        add(pane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    public Object getSelectedObject() {
        return list.getSelectedValue();

    }

    public void setSelectedObject(String str) {
        list.setSelectedValue(str, true);
    }

    public static DatabaseJList getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DatabaseJList();
        }
        return instance;

    }

    public static void main(String a[])
    {
        DatabaseJList list = DatabaseJList.getInstance();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.getContentPane().add(list);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: remember to place Swing-related events on the `EDT`!